# Updating an Image with Async

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So I have a database with a table where a User name corresponds to the name of an image. So In my AsyncHTTP I retrieve the Username and wish to map that Username to its correct image(all images are located in my drawable folder)

In my XML where this image will be rendered I just put an imageview and never assigned it an image(the Id for this imageView is myImage)

So how when I run my code the image is not rendered. I cant assign the image outside of async because of scope issues.

```
   Context context = this;



        AsyncHTTPPost asyncHttpPost2 = new AsyncHTTPPost(
                "http://lamp.ms.wits.ac.za/~s1363679/avatars.php", params) {

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {


                try {
                    JSONArray all = new JSONArray(s);
                    for (int i = 0; i < all.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject item = all.getJSONObject(i);

                        fName = item.getString("avatarName");
                        System.out.println();
                        Toast.makeText(Profile.this, fName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        ImageView Image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
                        System.out.println("");
                        theName = fName;
                        //String imagename="kaius";

                        Resources res = context.getResources();
                        int resID = res.getIdentifier(theName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
                        Image.setImageResource(resID);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };
        asyncHttpPost2.execute();



    }
```

The imageName is retrieved correctly and stored in the variable "theName" but it doesnt seem to render onto the view.

Answer (score 0):

At the same level of your drawable folder, there should also be some folders with these names:

-drawable-hdpi

-drawable-xhdpi

-drawable-xxhdpi

-drawable-xxxhdpi

Your images should be scaled according to different dpi´s and placed inside those folders to render correctly in all screens.

Another thing you could do instead, is:

```
  // get drawable path
  String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image;
  imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(imageUri , 1920, 1080));
```

And declare somewhere decodeSampledBitmapFromFile like this:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String imagePath,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + imagestoplay[currImage])
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    // BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

}
```

Don´t forget to change 1080 and 1920 to your required size in pixels.